# looking for a free site like vectormagic

Tags: website-design, photoshop

I am looking for a FREE site like [Vectormagic](http://vectormagic.com/) that takes pixellated images and makes them vector antialiased. any ideas? I need something I don't need to download. just upload an image and they antialias for you.

Comment: Can you explain how the example you gave isn't the answer to your own question?

Comment: I am looking for a free site. I only have one image right now and wondering if there was a free site...vectorimage is not free.

Answer (score 1):

The [Aviary vector editor](http://www.aviary.com/tools/vector-editor) has a trace feature. This [tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rw9vNl5Y4Zg) will give you an overview of process, though it's a couple years old and the menus have been rearranged a bit, so you'll have to adapt.

Comment: yes. thank you! the Aviary vector editor worked. the site is slow and it wouldn't let me save the image, but somehow I was able to print screen and save image in photoshop. the new image may not be best resolution and I had to do some editing in photoshop but it is 100X better than the original. Thanks!